# Get list of programs in notification-area using Python

Tags: python, system-tray, notification-area

Is it possible to get the list of actual programs (text obtained by mouse hover on icons [Example below]) in notification-area (System-tray) on Windows using Python ?

[Example of notification-area in Windows 7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENyKo.png)